# Ошибка "Индекс за пределами диапазона"

Tags: c#

Есть задача.
В принципе все работает, но выдает ошибку.

Напишите функцию, которая будет возвращать указанный элемент ряда Фибоначчи. Ряд Фибоначчи – это ряд, в котором каждый следующий элемент равен сумме двух предыдущих. 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21… Функция принимает порядковый номер элемента и возвращает соответствующий элемент.

Может быть, конечно, я что-то не так понял, но написал вот такой код:

```
public static int FibReturn(List<int>fib) 
{
    int x = 0, y = 1;
    int fib_a=fib[0];
    Console.Write("Введите номер позиции в ряду Фиббоначи: ");
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) // Добавяем необходимое кол-во элементов в список,
                                // согласно переменной a
    {
        fib.Add(fib[x] + fib[y]); 
        x++;
        y++;
        fib_a = fib[a-1];
    }
    return fib_a;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int fibq;
    List<int> fib = new List<int>() {0,1}; // создание списка
    int fib_a;
    fib_a = FibReturn(fib);
    Console.WriteLine(fib[0]);

    foreach (int item in fib)
        Console.Write(item + " ");

    Console.Read();
}
```

Все работает как надо, но ошибка в том, что при вводе значения от 1 до 3-х все работает ок.
При вводе 4+ выдает ошибку: "Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции."

Причем если содержимое функции FibReturn() написано в Main(), то все отлично работает.

По идее, цикл for должен прокручиваться "а" раз, но что-то не выходит.

Укажите, пожалуйста, мои ошибки, и желательно с пояснением.
Если я все не так, как нужно, в задании написал, сильно не ругайтесь. =))

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, лучше реализовать эту функцию через рекурсию. Был бы рад помочь, но, к сожалению, технически не могу.

Comment: @Valeriy Karchov: Вы имеете в виду решение с экспоненциальной сложностью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строке `fib_a = fib[a - 1];`.

Смотрите. Сначала размер списка 2, потом вы в цикле добавляете туда новые элементы. Но элемент с индексом `a - 1` там появится лишь в конце цикла.

Зачем вам на каждой итерации цикла перечитывать этот элемент? Читайте только по завершению цикла.

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам. Вот теперь все работает)

Comment: @Rafnsvartr: Пожалуйста!